# How to get single bounding box while detecting face using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, cascade-classifier

I do not get perfect accuracy while detecting a face using opencv.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

#create a cascadeclassifier object
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/yash/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
#create a cascade classifier.it will contain the features of the face

#reading the image as it is
img = cv2.imread("profile.JPG")

#reading the image as gray_scale image
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #converting colored image to gray scale

#search the co-ordinates of the image
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,scaleFactor = 1.05,minNeighbors=5)
#scaleFactor = decreases the shape value by 5%,until the face is found .smaller this value , the greater is the accuracy.
#detectMultiScale = method to search for the face rectangle co-ordinates

#print(type(faces))
#print(faces)

for x,y,w,h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)

resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(int(img.shape[1]/2) , int(img.shape[0]/2)))    
cv2.imshow("face detection",resized_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here there is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDayT.jpg) I am trying to get perfect accuracy on.

Comment: Looks quite good, what is wrong with it?

Comment: click on the image link . it will saw two rectangles

Comment: What do you mean by 'perfect'? 100% accuracy or only a single bounding box?

Comment: Achieving "perfect accuracy" is hardly achievable in any classification task. You may want to review that statement as this may confuse people.

Comment: single bounding box . if i upload portrait photo then it works well but the face is slightly right side or left side then it detects a face along with another box on my ear. you can click to  see on (image) link

Comment: @YashPatel thats not what 100% accuracy is about

Comment: how do i get only one bounding box ?.i got two on my face

Comment: For one face use flag CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT as last parameter in detectMultiScale

Comment: @Nuzhny not working ...

Answer (score 2):

For one face use flag CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT as last parameter in detectMultiScale.

But Haar cascades now are not the best choice for face detection. In OpenCV 4.0 developers remove code for Haar cascades training - they recommend to use DNN. [For example here](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/).

And second: OpenCV developers created an open source framework for DNN inference - [OpenVINO](https://github.com/opencv/dldt) and a lot of [pretrained models](https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo) (for face detection too). If you want to have the fastest face detector on CPU than you need to use OpenVINO.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Nuzhny's recommendation, you should use Non Maximum Suppression algorithm to solve the problem of multiple detections.

[Pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) has a very good article along with code on this topic which will help you.